# Scanner Freezes Program When No Input Is Given

Tags: java, pipe

I'm making an application that is mainly used with pipes. At the start of the program, here is how I get all my input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    input.add(scanner.nextLine());
}

scanner.close();
```

When used with pipes, this works well. For example, running `ls | java -jar ...` it prints out all the lines given from `ls`. However, when I just run `java -jar ...` with no input/pipe, it freezes and nothing happens. Even when I press enter and mash my keyboard it's still stuck. I can only stop the program by using ctrl-c. I think this is because there is nothing to read so Scanner waits until there is something to read. How do I read all lines from `System.in` without freezing, or is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Edit:
Whoever marked this as a duplicate clearly did not read my question. My question was to check if the `System.in` was empty to not freeze the program, not how to get past the input stage. It is freezing because there is nothing in `System.in` so Scanner is taking forever, but I want to check if there is nothing in `System.in`.

Answer:
Thank you @QiuZhou for the answer. I modified his second example to get this:

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (reader.ready()) {
    String nextLine = reader.readLine();
    input.add(nextLine);
}
```

and it works like a charm.

Comment: @RichardBarker Sorry for the bad wording in my question. I know why it's freezing, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: It is not "freezing", it is *waiting* for you to type some input, and it'll keep processing input until you end the input stream by pressing Ctrl+D

Comment: What have you tried to debug that "freezing"? What is the **expected** behaviour?

Comment: @NicoHaase There isn't really an excepted behavior, I know why it isn't working. What I want to know is how I can detect that stdin is empty, or the program was run without a pipe, so the scanner doesn't get stuck while looking for the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's freezing because, as you said, *there is nothing to read so Scanner waits until there is something to read*, but you want to *read all lines from System.in without freezing*, it sounds kind of conflicting to me, it's not like reading from a file, we don't know how many lines whoever using your program is going to type in, unless the person tell us. I suggest you define a special character as `end of input`, for example, `done`, when the person decides he has finished, just enter `done` to end waiting:

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Please enter something. Enter 'done' when finished.");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            if(nextLine.equals("done"))break;
            input.add(nextLine);
        }

        scanner.close();
```

To check if there is something to read in `System.in` without being stuck there, you can do it by using `BufferedReader.ready()`, as the document reads, *Note that in.ready() will return true if and only if the next read on the stream will not block.*

```
        System.out.println("Please enter something. Enter 'done' when finished.");

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true) {
            if (reader.ready()) {
                String nextLine = reader.readLine();
                if(nextLine.equals("done"))break;
                input.add(nextLine);
            }
            //since ready() will not block, you can add additional logic here, like if it
            //takes too long to read next line from input, you can just end here
            // break;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited the second one with the ready() method.